# Debugging Magento 2 cron errors when no message is left?

Tags: magento2, error, cron, debugging, magento2.3.5

Quite often when I'm attempting to create a CRON job I'll mess up along the way and the job will fail to run.

Typically I'd check my logs and see where I went wrong, put the missing semicolon back, and continue on my way, but when it comes to cron jobs Magento rarely gives you any information of substance.

The `messages` field is null in the `cron_jobs` table, no messages are left in the Php error logs, none in the magento exceptions, none in cron.log, and none anywhere else I can think of to check, but the job still gets an "error" status.

Am I just not looking in the correct place for these errors or is there some way to make the cron log them somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, setting

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Helped immensely. I was under the impression that error_reporting(E_ALL); would show errors and for the most part it did but under some circumstances, but setting the above line in app/bootstrap.php shows a lot more errors that I was not aware of due to no visible loss of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

(For those who came here from google as me, also for myself in the future.)

Just add some params to forward cron output to specific files, eg.

`php -d display_errors=1 bin/magento cron:run >> /path/to/cron.log 2>> /path/to/cron.error.log`